# MVC .NET 4.0 : Image Links

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html-helper

I was recently introduced to the HTMLhelper class....along with MVC in general.

Does MVC, or the HtmlHelper class give any alternates for image links...and static links?  For example, if I want to display an image on a webpage, do I still have to do the traditional href tag?

I.e. `<img src='/Content/Images/mypic.jpg' />`

or is there a better way to do it via MVC and/or HtmlHelper class.  I thought there may be a more dynamic linking approach that the HTMLhelper class may offer.

Thank You.

Comment: What do you need? As you can set other values by sending valuesto the view you can also set pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is relatively easy to [write one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/asp_net_mvc_imagelink.aspx).